How do I set up the lazy.nvim plugin installer in LazyVim?
So I'm trying to set up LazyVim, and so far I have almost everything set up regarding the requirements for lazyvim. I still haven't glued LazyVim and Neovim together, but I've been trying to figure out for a week now (with breaks whilst the time has passed).
I was initially going to use vim-plug as my plugin installer, but I asked Bing AI what I should use, and it said lazy.nvim is much better for Neovim users, and that it works better. I also was wondering about init.vim vs. init.lua, and it said lua is better as it allows for more customization. So I followed the AI's advice.
So when I do :edit $MYVIMRC, it lets me go into my lua file, and then I know I must follow the installation guide, but after I do the first step which is a simple copy and paste into the .lua file, I have these instructions:

So I'm honestly overwhelmed as someone who doesn't know anything other than semi-basic LuaLaTeX and VSCode for about a week, but I really want to be able to use Neovim because:

I've spent a lot of time trying to get it set up, and
I just wanna know what the fuss is about.

I really would only want to try to get vim-tex as the plugin I want as I'm primarily going to use Neovim for LuaLaTeX, but I want to get used to it if in case I ever want to get deeper into programming.

Welcome to the site. Some notes: 1) please share text as text, not images of text. 2) the Vim family of editors has a reputation for being hard on new users. Other editors are far more accessible (and less powerful). 3) I'd not recommend to pile a load of plugins on your Vim without having understood at least the basics.

This site is probably not the best for such general question where we usually focus on precise question with precise answers :-). If you are are a beginner my advice is to start with dead technologies where it will be easier to get more support (Neovim + vim-plug + vim-latex). If you want to feel the fuss but don't want to configure it maybe using a Neovim pre-configuration is an option (NvChad or LazyVim)

In you question you mention LazyVim do you mean lazy.nvim the plugin manager or LazyVim the pre-configuration?

Please don't post images of text: [edit] to include a link and the exact text. It would be helpful if you [edit]ed to respond to clarifying questions from Vivian, too.

Unsolicited advice: Take it slow, and consider if Vim is really the best fit for you. Don't rely on AI to learn it: Vim has the best editor documentation in the world (start with :help).

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allow the question to rest :-)

@VivianDeSmedt I'm so sorry! I just accepted your answer, i should have done that much earlier. Forgive me..

Thanks for the feedback. You are forgiven :-) I know how it goes trying to many rabbits, not having the time. It is absolutely not a problem :-)

If you are are a beginner my advice is to start with "dead" technologies where it will be easier for you to get support:

Neovim
vim-plug
vim-latex.

If you want to feel the fuss but don't want to configure it maybe using a Neovim pre-configuration is an option worth considering:
Popular options are:

NvChad
LunarVim
LazyVim

Or something in the middle:

KickStart.nvim

